# com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, jersey

I want to ask you a question about this exception. I need more information but i dont find anything. Actually this test i am receiving this exception:

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

The url also exists and retrieve me data if i put that url in a browser. The exception raises in the line of the ClientResponse. Please give more info. Actually im using a proxy to establish connection with the server , but my data are OK, in my project.properties. Any idea why happens this??. Im communicating with a remote server , no in localhost.

```
    Client client = Client.create();

                WebResource webResource = client
                   .resource("http://someurl");

   String input= "{'test'}";
                ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
                   .post(ClientResponse.class, input);
```